# Curl: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue message on File Upload

Tags: python, django, curl, django-file-upload

I'm uploading a file using curl in one of my django project, it works fine in localhost, but when I hosted the project in remote server, it does not work.

I'm sending the file from this command

```
curl -i --form docfile=@/path_to_file http://example.com/process-file
```

and in views.py, I'm handling this file as

```
def process_file(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('Only POST Method')

    docfile = request.FILES['docfile']

    output = main(0, docfile) # output is json object
    return HttpResponse(output,content_type = "application/json")
```

This works perfectly fine when i run in local machine, but sending POST request to remote server with curl returns

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

and do nothing. File is getting uploaded. What should I do.

Thanks

Edit 1:
I tried to send some other HttpResponse (file name) from other view method, its working fine, but when i process file, it just sends HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how to fix this in your project, but it looks like your `curl` is sending the `Expect: 100-continue` header, prompting the remote server to send back `HTTP/1.1 Continue`. `curl` waits to get back that response then uploads the form. You say `curl` returns the `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` then "does nothing," but it should actually be uploading after it receives that, so maybe whatever callback you're using isn't returning that. I would try looking at it with Wireshark.